# Set custom fonts in strings

Tags: android, fonts, android-xml, android-fonts

I have a custom fonts `BebasNeue.otf` which i want to set in the strings variables. I have searched a lot but did not get any solution.

I know we can set the custom fonts in views like `textView.setTypeface(font);`. But now i want to set the fonts to the `Strings` which i have as below :

```
String Name,Contact;
 Name="ABCD";
 Contact="97696538";
```

This all the strings contains some values. Now i want to set the custom fonts to all the strings which is below:

```
 Typeface fontString = Typeface.createFromAsset(m_context.getAssets(),
            "BebasNeue.otf");
```

Can any one tell me how can i set the above fonts in my Strings variable.

Any help will be appreciated .

Thanks.

Comment: Hi where do u want to display these strings??

Comment: I am showing this strings on the image which i am drawing on canvas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have resolved my issue as below and with the help of the comments provided by `@ASP` .

```
 Typeface fontString = Typeface.createFromAsset(m_context.getAssets(),
                "BebasNeue.otf");
   Paint paint = new Paint();
   paint.setTypeface(fontString);
   mCanvas.drawText("ID :" + m_sId, dw - 450, dh - 350, paint);
```

Thanks all for helping me and quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help.

```
public class TypefaceSpan extends MetricAffectingSpan {
/** An <code>LruCache</code> for previously loaded typefaces. */
private static LruCache<String, Typeface> sTypefaceCache = new LruCache<String, Typeface>(
        12);

private Typeface mTypeface;

/**
 * Load the {@link Typeface} and apply to a {@link Spannable}.
 */
public TypefaceSpan(Context context, String typefaceName) {
    mTypeface = sTypefaceCache.get(typefaceName);

    if (mTypeface == null) {
        mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getApplicationContext().getAssets(), 
                                             String.format("%s", typefaceName));

        // Cache the loaded Typeface
        sTypefaceCache.put(typefaceName, mTypeface);
    }
}

@Override
public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint p) {
    p.setTypeface(mTypeface);

    // Note: This flag is required for proper typeface rendering
    p.setFlags(p.getFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
}

@Override
public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {
    tp.setTypeface(mTypeface);

    // Note: This flag is required for proper typeface rendering
    tp.setFlags(tp.getFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
}
}
```

And use it like this

```
SpannableString s = new SpannableString("My Title");
s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "MyTypeface.otf"), 0, s.length(),
        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```